# What is the etiquette of linking files in SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, answers

This is inspired by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1215966/456385)

Personally, I'm always be on guard when someone on internet share files on private file sharing sites, like mediafire, google drive, and such. This one, particularly, share files in not-so-known (at least for me) website, which further increase my suspicion.

There are various questions in SuperUser, which (sometimes) may be solved by uploading the correct dll* (for example directX), or an example of working Excel file.

1. Are we allowed to upload files as an answer?
2. If yes, what are the etiquettes?

The obvious part is disclosing you are the author of the files (so you will be held responsible in cases when the files are malicious, or inadvertently infected with malware)

*I'm aware that sharing dll files is **a bad idea**, even more downloading one from any site but the official source, but I can't think of better example.

Comment: Personally I would not download anything from an unknown source. In this particular case the downloads are not even necessary as there are manual instructions in the answer. I have therefore removed the links.

Comment: I can't see it mentioned in the duplicate but in general I would prefer reputable and long lived sources over file sharing sites as a file sharing sites may remove a file without notice and for other obvious reason related to system security and malware. In general though it's not explicitly forbidden, but any link to file sharing site should be considered harmful until proven otherwise.